Shiny App keeps getting disconnected from server (only works after multiple reloads)
I'm encountering an issue with my Shiny app. It keeps getting disconnected from the server, and the only way I can get it to work is by clicking reload around 10 times. The logs don't show any errors. Has anyone experienced something similar or have any suggestions on how to fix this?
2024-05-31T10:03:32.459573+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   meta_Browser = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.464524+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   meta_Version = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.469311+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   `meta_Operating System` = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.474291+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   meta_Resolution = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.479509+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   height_male_cm = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.484553+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   weight_male_kg = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.489709+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   height_female_cm = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.495436+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   height_female_inches_3 = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.500224+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   weight_female_kg = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.505657+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   sex_55_TEXT = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.510581+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   religion.identificat_9_TEXT = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.515766+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   debrief.comment = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.520976+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   Q_Language = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:32.527512+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   testing = col_logical()
2024-05-31T10:03:32.532506+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   # ... with 5 more columns
2024-05-31T10:03:32.538553+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: )
2024-05-31T10:03:32.543668+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: ℹ Use `spec()` for the full column specifications.
2024-05-31T10:03:32.548719+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: 
2024-05-31T10:03:32.553575+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: Your original .Renviron will be backed up and stored in your R HOME directory if needed.
2024-05-31T10:03:32.560939+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: Your Qualtrics key and base URL have been stored in your .Renviron.  
2024-05-31T10:03:32.565862+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: To use now, restart R or run `readRenviron("~/.Renviron")`
2024-05-31T10:03:35.405457+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:     |                                                                               |                                                                      |   0%   |                                                                               |========================                                              |  34%   |                                                                               |================================================                      |  69%   |                                                                               |======================================================================| 100%
2024-05-31T10:03:37.274785+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: 
2024-05-31T10:03:37.280132+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: ── Column specification ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2024-05-31T10:03:37.285433+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: cols(
2024-05-31T10:03:37.290817+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   .default = col_double(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.296958+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   StartDate = col_datetime(format = ""),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.302653+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   EndDate = col_datetime(format = ""),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.308441+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   RecordedDate = col_datetime(format = ""),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.313395+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   ResponseId = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.318623+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   DistributionChannel = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.323711+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   UserLanguage = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.328743+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   meta_Browser = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.333643+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   meta_Version = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.338800+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   `meta_Operating System` = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.344076+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   meta_Resolution = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.349141+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   height_male_cm = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.354627+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   weight_male_kg = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.360695+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   height_female_cm = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.365949+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   height_female_inches_3 = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.370929+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   weight_female_kg = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.376164+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   sex_55_TEXT = col_logical(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.381410+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   religion.identificat_9_TEXT = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.386601+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   debrief.comment = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.391587+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   Q_Language = col_character(),
2024-05-31T10:03:37.396624+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   testing = col_logical()
2024-05-31T10:03:37.401349+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:   # ... with 5 more columns
2024-05-31T10:03:37.406578+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: )
2024-05-31T10:03:37.413837+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]: ℹ Use `spec()` for the full column specifications.
2024-05-31T10:03:37.418699+00:00 shinyapps[12060394]:


have you tryed setting a timout?
options(shiny.autoreload = TRUE)
shiny::runApp(timeout = 6000)

@pbraeutigm Error in shiny::runApp(timeout = 6000) : unused argument (timeout = 6000)
